# How to sort formula field in Crystal Report 11?

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

I have a formula field. Now I wants to short the field. But I could not add the field in sort.

Is there any other way to sort by this formula field in Crystal Report 11?.

Here is my formula **Account**

```
trim({GL00100.ACTNUMBR_6})+'-'+trim({GL00100.ACTNUMBR_1})+'-'+trim({GL00100.ACTNUMBR_2})+'-'+trim({GL00100.ACTNUMBR_3})+'-'+trim({GL00100.ACTNUMBR_4})+'-'+trim({GL00100.ACTNUMBR_5})+'-'+trim({GL00100.ACTNUMBR_6})
```

Comment: You should definitely be able to add this formula in sorting. Is that the whole formula or is there more?

Comment: Seems like it should work to me, try putting a `totext` function around it, maybe in another formula (ie `totext(@account)`) and see if you can sort that. It's possible you've got a data type issue.